# CodeIgniter set_userdata() triggers server 500 error

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, user-data

1. CodeIgniter Issue: Server 500 Error. 
       Whenever I call set_userdata() function, it triggers Server 500 Error. Sample code of login is below. I'm hosting it on SiteGround. if I remove  set_userdata function, the code works fine except login won't work.

> ```
> <?php 
> if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
>     // LOGIN MODEL 
>     class Login_model extends CI_Model{
>         function __construct(){
>             parent::__construct();
>         } // VALIDATE METHOD
>         public function validate(){       // grab user input
>      $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
>      $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
>         $this->db->where('username', $username);
>         $this->db->where('password', sha1($password));
>         $this -> db -> where('activated', 'yes');// Run the query<br>
>         $query = $this->db->get('user_account');// Let's check if there are any results
>         if($query->num_rows == 1)// If there is a user, then create session data 
>         {
>             $row = $query->row();
>             $data = array(
>                     'id' => $row->serial,
>                     'name' => $row->name,
>                     'email' => $row->email,
>                     'password' => $row->password,
>                     'type' => $row->type,
>                     'address' => $row -> address,
>                     'phone' => $row -> phone,
>                     'pic' => $row -> pic,<br>
>                     'validated' => true
>                     );
>             $this->session->set_userdata($data);
>             return true;
>         }// If the previous process did not validate
>         return false;// then return false.
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ?>

Comment: are you load session library

Comment: in application/config/autoload.php ; autoload the "session" library if not done so already.

Comment: @Adarsh Yeah I've already loaded session library..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the 500 error is thrown when calling set_userdata?

First thing you can do is enable error_reporting. One way to do this is by setting your environment to 'development' in your main index.php file, provided also that you have enabled error reporting in your php.ini. After doing this you will probably see a more detailed error message that will help you identify the problem.

On the other hand looking at your code I see the line `'pic' => $row -> pic,<br>` and that `<br>` definitely produces an error when initializing your array, maybe this is the case

Comment: Thanks! You're a lifesaver! Removing 'pic' => $row -> pic.  solved the problem! Actually the problem was that BLOB was saved in DB instead of image path. 

**Summary:** Saving large amount of data in session caused the problem. 

According to (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) 

**Note:** Cookies can only hold 4KB of data, so be careful not to exceed the capacity. The encryption process in particular produces a longer data string than the original so keep careful track of how much data you are storing.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass params to your model and don't call "$this->input->post('username')" in it

Params :

`public function validate($user, $pass){`

Also verify you have loaded security and db lib.